# Mysql query comma separated filter result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, filter

My table looks like this

```
id pname     pfilter
1  onename   24, 36, 120
2  another   22, 124, 1
3  yet       120, 12, 124
```

I´m trying to run this query:

```
$filterrun = "24";

SELECT * FROM table WHERE pfilter LIKE '$filterrun'
```

In this example i would like only id #1 to show up. And not id #2 and #3 since these contains pfilter 124.

How can this be done?

Comment: The recommended method is to normalize your database; MySQL's FIND_IN_SET is a lazy-mans alternative, but is less performant because you can't index on pfilter effectively

Answer (score 1):

try this with `FIND_IN_SET`

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('$filterrun', pfilter)
```

if you have speces then you can use this

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('$filterrun',replace(replace(pfilter, ', ', ','),' ,',','))
```

EDIT: it would be hard if you have spaces between values , you can also go around them like that.

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE  
    pfilter LIKE ' $filterrun,%' 
    or pfilter like '$filterrun,%'
    or pfilter like '%,$filterrun,%'
    or pfilter like '%, $filterrun,%'
    or pfilter like '%,$filterrun ,%'
    or pfilter like '%,$filterrun %'
    or pfilter like '%, $filterrun'
```

Or use this

```
   SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('$filterrun',pfilter) 
                            or FIND_IN_SET(' $filterrun',pfilter)
                            or FIND_IN_SET('$filterrun ',pfilter)
```

Note here: that there is spaces before and after `$filterrun`.

[**DEMO TO PLAY WITH**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56fd1/13)

Comment: If `pfilter` has values like `24, 36, 120` ( see spaces ), `FIND_IN_SET` is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your data contains a comma-space delimited list.  This gives you two direct methods:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE concat(', ', $filterrun, ', ') like concat('%, ', pfilter, ', %');
```

Or a slight variation on echo_me's solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE find_in_set($filterrun, replace(pfilter, ', ', ','));
```

Otherwise, you have to start dealing with the spaces.

Ultimately, though, you should be using a separate association/junction table.  This would have one row per id and filter value.